# Safari seems not sending If-Modified-Since header for main address

Tags: safari, http-headers, last-modified, if-modified-since

After looking (carefully...) in the different questions and answers of the forum (and others), I didn't find a definitive answer.
When Safari requests a resource (page, image...) to a web server it doesn't provide If-Modified-Since header for the main resource of the request. That means the web server can't answer "resource not modified, use your cache". This is not the behavior of other browsers and not good in terms of performance for the web server as well as for the user.

However Safari sends this If-Modified-Since for the sub-elements of the resource (e.g. images, css in a page...). Which is good.

So I think Safari deliberately decided not to send this header for the main requested resource, but to be 100% sure, do you know a way to influence Safari's behavior to provide a If-Modified-Since for the main resource requested to the server?

acama,

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the behaviour of Safari's cache headers is the subject of a bug. There was a [WebKit issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18972) opened about it and subsequently closed because the bug appears in Safari itself.